# FireFox: force forget own client certificates

Tags: firefox, certificate

I'm using FireFox 22.0 on Windows 7 and have a couple of client certificates registered which are outdated now. When I go to Tools|Options|Advanced|Encryption|View Certificates|Your Certificates, select all my certificates, click `Delete...` and confirm with `OK` the certificates seem gone (none are shown). Pressing `OK` in the Certificate Manager and reopening it shows the certificates again. Is this a known bug?

How can I reliable delete the certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the profile directory one can find a file `cert8.db`. Deleting this worked.